# What method is equivalent to_internal_value in DRF 2?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can not find this in the documentation.

I remember that I used such a method in DRF 2 but can not recall the name.

Answer (score 0):

This was `from_native` as described in the [release notes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#changes-to-the-custom-field-api)